# LibGdx: Is it possible to return two keys held down at the same time?

Tags: java, input, libgdx, listener

Would something like this be possible?
I know there is Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(int key).

```
public class KeyListener implements EventListener {

public boolean handle(Event e) {
    if (!(e instanceof InputEvent)) return false;
    InputEvent event = (InputEvent) e;

    if (event.getType() == InputEvent.Type.keyDown) keysPressed(event.getKeyCode(), keycode????)
}

public boolean keysPressed(int firstKey, int secondKey) {

}
```

}

EDIT: How would it be possible to return the second keyCode?

Comment: Have you tried to run the code yet?

Comment: Yes, in Java you can tell if any combination of `Ctrl`, `Alt`, and `Shift` are being simultaneously pressed.

Comment: Also the `Windows` key, a.k.a., `Meta`.

Comment: And how can I return the second keyCode?

Comment: @DarioKowalski--I just noticed your EDIT and comment above. At present, the return type of your `keysPressed` methd is `boolean`. Are you saying that you want `keysPressed` to return the `int` values of both (or all) keys being pressed? Or will detecting those keys inside the method suffice? Also did you see the 3 edits to my Answer?

Comment: @DarioKowalski--by the way, I've written a couple of lame game programs with no animation but plenty of drag and drop and keypress combinations to deal with. One took forever. But it is SO good (and, serously, I NEVER brag) that I have to tell you to stay with it, regardless of how impossible it seems at times. One day it'll work. And then you'll say, "Hmmm... now how can I improve this?" And be back here with more problems to solve! Great life!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't notice the other answer before I typed this answer out, but this method has a few advantages. It uses an InputProcessor, which is the proper way if you need to play nice with other input processors and Stage2D; you don't have to iterate through 255 keys every frame; and it only fires once per key press instead of on every frame.

There isn't an automatic way to handle multiple key presses, but it's pretty easy to implement your own. Libgdx comes with an IntSet class that is perfect for this and avoids generating garbage because it uses primitive ints.

```
private final IntSet downKeys = new IntSet(20);

private InputAdapter inputAdapter = new InputAdapter(){
    public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {
        downKeys.add(keycode);
        if (downKeys.size >= 2){
            onMultipleKeysDown(keycode);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean keyUp (int keycode) {
        downKeys.remove(keycode);
        return true;
    }
};

private void onMultipleKeysDown (int mostRecentKeycode){
    //Keys that are currently down are in the IntSet. Do whatever you like, for example:

    //Alt-F4 to quit:
    if (downKeys.contains(Input.Keys.ALT_LEFT) || downKeys.contains(Input.Keys.ALT_RIGHT)){
        if (downKeys.size == 2 && mostRecentKeycode == Input.Keys.F4){
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void show() {
    downKeys.clear();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to trap keypress combos, this for a particular `JMenuItem` named `mniPrefUnlimitedReuse`:

```
mniPrefUnlimitedReuse.setAccelerator(getKeyStroke(VK_U, 
    SHIFT_DOWN_MASK | CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
```

The menu item is acted on when user presses `Ctrl-Shift-U`.

You might also need code something a little like this, which is part of actual code I've written for an app:

```
  private  void cellsKeyPressedAction(KeyEvent e)
  {
    int key  = e.getKeyCode();
    int mods = e.getModifiers();

    if(key == VK_DELETE || key == BKSP || key == VK_SPACE)
      ... do same thing if the delete, backspace or space bar is hit ...

    if((mods & CTRL_MASK)  == CTRL_MASK)  ctrlIsDown  = true ;
    if((mods & SHIFT_MASK) == SHIFT_MASK) shiftIsDown = true;

    if(ctrlIsDown && shiftIsDown && key == VK_V)
      ... do something when user presses `Ctrl-Shift-V` ...

    if(     ctrlIsDown 
         && key > 0 
      )
        ... do something if user presses, e.g., `Ctrl-A` among others ...
```

To invoke that code for an object named `cells` requires a `KeyListener` for `keyPressed`:

```
    cells.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
         public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
         {
            cellsKeyPressedAction(e);
         }
     });
```

***EDIT***

Given that you want to do it using `libgdx`, surely the logic and calls would be similar. E.g., what I found at github under `libgdx/libgdx` for `tests/gdx-tests-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/lwjgl/LwjglTestStarter.java` looks like pure `Java`. I don't know if you can find similar routines for `libgdx`--why would you want to?

```
list.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) 
                       ... do something ...
                }
            });
```

I have no experience with `libgdx`, so I have no idea what would require replacing `Java` routines to check for key presses.

So maybe Google?

***EDIT 2***

Oh. "No java" routines. But why? I guess I am showing my ignorance. But I guess here's why:

`The libgdx project is an open-source cross-platform game development library written in Java. It abstracts away the differences between writing OpenGL-based games on various platforms.`

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464011/libgdx-check-if-a-key-is-being-held-down) may help. And definitely [this tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/15/LibGDX-Tutorial-4-Handling-the-mouse-and-keyboard.aspx). And [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96109/libgdx-how-to-efficiently-handle-button-presses). [And this](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html). [And finally](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling).

Again, I think once you learn what the routines' names are, the `keysPressed` method will look a lot like my `Java` routine, just with slightly different names and parameter lists.

**EDIT 3**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692838/get-key-code-as-well-as-key-modifiers-on-key-press) may be best of all. Maybe modify it like so after consulting [this](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.Keys.html):

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
      boolean ctrl, alt, shift, ...;
      if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT_SHIFT) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT_SHIFT)) {
            shift = true;
      } 
      if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.CONTROL_LEFT) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.CONTROL_RIGHT))) {
          ctrl = true;
      } 
      if( Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ALT_LEFT) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ALT_RIGHT))) {
          alt = true;
      }
      // Finally, choose an action based on the key combination pressed
      if (shift && keycode == Input.Keys.A) {
          // What to do if Shift+A is pressed
      } else if (/* and so on */) {
          //...     
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks 4 your answer but I whant all done with libGDX and no java libs.

Comment: I'll bet it's something similar in form, though.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check all pressed keys without any listeners the simpliest solution is to use **Gdx.input.isKeyPressed** method and passing to it all integer identifiers of keys.

In the **Input.Keys** class there is list of all keys like:

```
    public static final int I = 37;
    public static final int J = 38;
    public static final int K = 39;
    public static final int L = 40;
    ...
```

and you can see that the maximum is number for a key is 255 (BUTTON_CIRCLE) so we will just iterate from 0-255 checking whether the key is pressed. Then add the pressed key's id to an array and check if desired combination is there.

All in all the code should look like:

```
    //this should not be in the render function!
    Array<Integer> pressedButtons = new Array<Integer>();

    ...
    //this should be in the render function

    pressedButtons.clear();

    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        if( Gdx.input.isKeyPressed( i ) )
            pressedButtons.add( i );

    if(pressedButtons.contains(Keys.CONTROL_LEFT, false) && pressedButtons.contains(Keys.ALT_LEFT, false) && pressedButtons.contains(Keys.M, false))
    {
        System.out.println("PRESSED!");
    }
```

you can add some flag to the if so it will be fired only once